# pivots in mysql with n number of rows

Tags: mysql, pivot, pivot-table

I want to do pivots on **dominant**(table_name) with N number of rows, here is the structure of my table

```
billingid   sku_id   qty
   1          101     1
   1          102     2
   1          106     5 
   2          107     3
   2          109     2
   2          108     1 
   2          201     1
   3          205     5 
   4          209     2
   .           .      .
   .           .      . 
   .           .      .
   n           n      n
```

and here is the format which is desired

```
billingid  101  102  106  107  109  108  201  205 ... n
   1
   2                 **SUM OF QTY*** 
   3                
   4                 **SUM OF QTY*** 
   .
   .
   .                 **SUM OF QTY*** 
   n
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then ask a specifiq question and not in general how you can do dynamic pivoting. Because I would simply repeat the 2nd part of the code in the accepted answer.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer if that's available (e.g. a bit of PHP)